# why my code doesn't work

Tags: education

```
my code is


eqn = A ((3 n + 1)/(n + 1)) ( 1 - (r/R)^((n + 1)/n) * B) == 
  C *(n/r) * D[T[r], {r, 2}]
DSolve[{eqn, T[R] == Tw, T'[0] == 0}, T[r], r]
```

output is

```
DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in {(A (1+3 n) (1-B (r/R)^((1+n)/n)))/(1+n)==(C n \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(T[R] == Tw\)]\(\*SuperscriptBox["T", "\[Prime]\[Prime]",
```

MultilineFunction->None][r])))/r} should literally match the independent variables.

Comment: No error in 11.3. btw, do not use `C` as variable as it is used internally for constants of integrations. Try  with clean kernel? and do not use subscripted variables. Use normal variables.

Comment: so what your suggestion?

Comment: As Nasser said, restart your kernel, and do not use `C`.  Voting to close as unreproducible (tried in versions 11.3, 11.0 and 10.3).

Comment: solved thanks .....................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` ClearAll["Global`*"] ``

and don't use `C` as a constant.

Comment: It's `C`, not `c`.

Comment: thanks.........................

Comment: after get solution , how can i put n=1 ? i mean what is code ?